# How to use JasperReports with Hibernate Annotations

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports

My application uses Hibernate with annotations. I want to use JasperReports with Hibernate, but when I try to create DataAdapter with JasperSoft eclipse plugin, it asks me for Hibernate config files, but I dont have them.

I am new to JasperReports. Any pointers to how to use JasperReports with Hibernate annotations will be helpful.

Comment: I am facing a similar requirement. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: The accepted answer in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257598/how-to-scan-packages-for-hibernate-entities-instead-of-using-hbm-xml) is maybe what you are looking for