# How to scan hibernate entities package in struts2,spring3 application instead of using cfg.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate

I know this question may be a duplicate. I saw the link
[[How to scan packages for Hibernate entities instead of using hbm.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257598/how-to-scan-packages-for-hibernate-entities-instead-of-using-hbm-xml][1])

In my application using Struts2,hibernate3,and spring3 
though I successfully removed the xml file for DAO and Service via `<context:component-scan>` in `applicationcontext.xml`, when I tried to use 
`<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.iris.admin"></property>` it throws some `typeNotMatchException` and `Session factory BeanCreationException

Below is My Configuration File

```
...............hibernate.cfg.xml............................................
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.vaib.admin.languageMaster.bean.Menu" />
        <mapping class="com.vaib.admin.companyType.bean.CompanyType" />
        <mapping class="com.vaib.admin.companyType.bean.CompanyTypeModified" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

applicationcontext-DataSource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="${jdbc.maxConnectionAge}" />
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${jdbc.checkoutTimeout}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${jdbc.acquireRetryAttempts}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${jdbc.initialPoolSize}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${jdbc.maxIdleTime}" />
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="${jdbc.autoCommitOnClose}" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${jdbc.unreturnedConnectionTimeout}" />
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${jdbc.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces}"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.db_url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${jdbc.testConnection}" />
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection"value="${jdbc.maxStatementsPerConnection}" />
    </bean>
```

application-Context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.iris.webservices.controller"></context:component-scan> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vaib"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="preparerFactoryClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <import resource="applicationContext-datasource.xml" /> -->
    <import resource="applicationPersistence.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationService.xml" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-datasource.xml</value>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property> -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vaib.admin"></property>
        <!-- <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">ifileprod</prop>
                <!-- Local DB -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">iFileProd</prop> -->

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="subCategory" class="com.iris.admin.subcategory.bean.SubCategory"></bean> -->
<!--    <bean id="menuPreparer" class="com.iris.admin.menuMngt.preparer.MenuViewPreparer"></bean> -->
<!--    <bean id="applicationStartListener" class="com.iris.listener.ApplicationStartListener"></bean> -->
<!--    <bean id="applicationClosedListener" class="com.iris.listener.ApplicationClosedListener"></bean> -->
</beans>
```

I have following Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vaib.admin.category.dao.CategoryDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vaib.admin.category.dao.CategoryDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 37 more
```

I couldn't understand why it comes while in seperate application it works fine when i am using packageTOScan attribute

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace

Comment: Ok. I see the exception now.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

You have commented line

```
<!-- <import resource="applicationContext-datasource.xml" /> -->
```

Remove the comment and it should work fine

Comment: provided the applicationcontext-datasource in session factory value attribute it show same error when i uncomment the <import resource="applicationContext-datasource.xml" />