# Hibernate Native Query with 5.2.10

Tags: java, hibernate

Under Hibernate < 5.2, it was possible to have generic SQL queries like

```
String sql = "select a, b, sum (c) csum from a group by a, b";
SQLQuery q = session.createSqlQuery (sql);
q
    .addScalar ("a", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar ("b", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar ("csum", IntegerType.INSTANCE);
q.setResultTransformer (new AliasToBeanResultTransformer (RankingModel.class));
List<RankingModel> results = q.list ();
```

Where `RankingModel` looks like:

```
public class RankingModel
{
    public int a, b, csum;
}
```

However, with 5.2, `addScalar()`, `setResultTransformer()` have all been deprecated, with the recommendation to use `session.createNativeQuery()` instead. The nearest equivalent to the above I have is:

```
String sql = "select a, b, sum (c) csum from a group by a, b";
NativeQuery<RankingModel> q = session.createNativeQuery (sql, RankingModel.class);
List<RankingModel> results = q.list ();
```

However, this code fails with:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ... RankingModel] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ... RankingModel
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImplementor.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.internal.NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.createQueryPlan(NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNativeQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:992)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:148)
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post your `RankingModel.java`? It seems like that object doesn't have `a`, `b`, and `sum` as instance variables.

Comment: The in the javadoc, after the deprecation warning, there is this comment : `@todo
develop a new approach to result transformers`... There might be no defined migration path for now. This nearest concept is `ResultSetMapping`, but i'm not sure it is as flexible as resultset transformers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix by using

```
String sql = "select a, b, sum (c) csum from a group by a, b";
NativeQuery<?> q = session.createNativeQuery (sql);
List<RankingModel> results = (List<RankingModel>)q.list ();
```

It will work but in IDE it will throw warning.

Or

```
String sql = "select a, b, sum (c) csum from a group by a, b";
    NativeQuery<?> q = session.createNativeQuery (sql).addSynchronizedEntityClass( RankingModel.class );
    List<RankingModel> results = (List<RankingModel>)q.list ();
```

Comment: Nope. I've talked to the developers, and it a TODO.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT a, b, sum(c) csum FROM a GROUP BY a, b";
NativeQuery<RankingModel> q = session.createNativeQuery(sql, RankingModel.class);
List<RankingModel> results = q.list();
```

Comment: what if I just want a HashMap with alias instead of Entity class object

Answer (score 0):

To tell Hibernate to use custom entity (data bean) classes like `RankingModel.java`, you have to annotate each such class with `@Entity` and each assignable column (field) with either `@Id` or `@Column`, as per JPA specification. In fact, Hibernate does its best to respect JPA 2.0 contract and supports all relevant Java annotations from `javax.persistence` package.

While doing so, make sure each entity class has a unique identifier field as mentioned in [hibernate exception: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com..domain.idea.MAE_MFEView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381290/hibernate-exception-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified)

Here is what your entity class should look like:

```
@Entity
public class RankingModel
{
    @Id
    public int id;

    @Column
    public int a;

    @Column
    public int b;

    @Column
    public int csum;
}
```

If the entity is to be persisted in the database, then the class has to be annotated with `@Table`, as well. This explicitly tells Hibernate which database table to use for the entity persistence. For fetching the data only, annotation is not necessary, I believe.

Finally, tell Hibernate to actually look up all the (annotated) entity classes. This can be achieved by referencing them from `hbm.xml`, or, for Java purists like myself, by listing Java packages to scan as an argument to `LocalSessionFactoryBean` constructor, as nicely explained in [How to scan packages for Hibernate entities instead of using hbm.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257598/how-to-scan-packages-for-hibernate-entities-instead-of-using-hbm-xml)

Comment: Addding an @Entity creates a physical table, which I don't want.